# span text IE problems

Tags: jquery

i have a problem to get the value of a span in IE. Is working on FF, and chrome but not in IE.
I made a simple version in http://jsfiddle.net/p38Mm/1/ basically i click a Row with 2 column and there is a span in the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `srcElement` is the input button not the `tr` that you have attached the event so to fix it, you have to address the right parent. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGCVJ/1/). In essence:

```
btnAddClick = function (e) {
    var tr = e.currentTarget ? $(e.currentTarget) : $(e.srcElement).parents('tr');
    alert(tr.find('span[id$=\'lblItem\']').html());
};
```

Comment: Why only in IE? and I associated the event in TR <tr onclick="btnAddClick(event)"> in real code I had also   StopPropagation(e); Edit I got it for IE part because of e.srcElement. Thanks alot for the solution

Comment: IE (<9) relies on `srcElement` whereas the other browsers use `currentTarget`.